# Why array data structure is more suitable as compare to other data structure in following applications?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, comparison

- Matrices use arrays which are used in different fields like image processing, computer graphics, and many more..
- It is also used in speech processing, in which each speech signal is
  an array.
- Your viewing screen is also a multidimensional array of    pixels.
- Book titles in a Library Management Systems.
- Online ticket    booking.
- Contact lists on mobile phones
- For CPU scheduling in computer.
- To    store the possible moves of chess on a chessboard.
- To store images of    a specific size on an android or laptop.
- IoT applications use arrays as we know that the number of values in
  an array will remain constant, and also that the accessing will be
  faster.

Above are the applications where array data Structure is used, but why we use  array instead of other data structures? Why array is suitable? What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

How you define an array??

An array is a collection of similar data-type. It has a property of random access of element in constant time. Array stores data sequentially so do RAM have data blocks in sequence, which means efficient management of memory and faster read/write operations. Another reason is easy to implement.

It is a primary data structure, all other data structure somehow or other way uses array to store their data and property, like Min Heap and Max Heap, Binary Tree, etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).